# Why do I get "Can't locate loadable object for module IO in @INC" when I try to install PAR::Packer with Strawberry Perl?

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl

I am trying to package a Perl script into a standalone form under Windows 7.  The Perl distro is Strawberry Perl, and the script runs fine under that.

When I went to install PAR::Packer, many of the unit tests failed with the same error.  I have also uninstalled and reinstalled Strawberry Perl.

The Strawberry Perl version is 5.24.0.1, and the PAR::Packer version is 1.035.

Here is the partial output when I attempt to install from cpan:

```
c:\Users\peter\Desktop\SW_Convert_V8>cpan PAR::Packer
Loading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.211)
Database was generated on Thu, 15 Dec 2016 19:29:58 GMT

Running install for module 'PAR::Packer'
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.95)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.069)
Checksum for C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\sources\authors\id\R\RS\RSCHUPP\PAR-Packer-1.035.tar.gz ok
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v2.06)
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.2304)
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.62)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta::Requirements loaded ok (v2.140)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v1.4417)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150005)
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20160507)
Configuring R/RS/RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.035.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Prototype mismatch: sub main::prompt: none vs ($;$) at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm line 240.
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for PAR::Packer
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.035.tar.gz
  C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for R/RS/RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.035.tar.gz
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----      RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.035.tar.gz     ----
    Module::Signature [requires,optional]
    Tk::Getopt [requires,optional]
    Tk::EntryCheck [requires,optional]
    Tk::ColoredButton [requires,optional]
    Tk [requires,optional]
cp lib/PAR/Filter.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter.pm
cp lib/PAR/Filter/Bytecode.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter\Bytecode.pm
cp lib/PAR/StrippedPARL/Base.pm blib\lib\PAR\StrippedPARL\Base.pm
cp lib/PAR/Filter/PodStrip.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter\PodStrip.pm
cp lib/PAR/Filter/Bleach.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter\Bleach.pm
cp lib/PAR/Packer.pm blib\lib\PAR\Packer.pm
cp lib/PAR/Filter/PatchContent.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter\PatchContent.pm
cp lib/pp.pm blib\lib\pp.pm
cp lib/App/Packer/PAR.pm blib\lib\App\Packer\PAR.pm
cp lib/PAR/Filter/Obfuscate.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter\Obfuscate.pm
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" par_pl2c.pl my_par_pl < ..\script\par.pl > my_par_pl.c
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" sha1.c.PL
gcc -c -s -O2 -DWIN32  -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields  -I"C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE"  -DPARL_EXE=\"parl.exe\" -DPAR_PAC
KER_VERSION=\"1.035\" -s -O2 main.c
windres -i winres/pp.rc -o ppresource.coff --input-format=rc --output-format=coff --target=pe-i386
g++ main.o ppresource.coff -s   -s -L"C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE" -L"C:\STRAWB~1\c\lib"  "C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\libperl524.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libmoldname.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-
w64-mingw32\lib\libkernel32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libuser32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libgdi32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libwinspool.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w
64-mingw32\lib\libcomdlg32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libadvapi32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libshell32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libole32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w
64-mingw32\lib\liboleaut32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libnetapi32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libuuid.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libws2_32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64
-mingw32\lib\libmpr.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libwinmm.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libversion.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libodbc32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw3
2\lib\libodbccp32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libcomctl32.a" -o par.exe
rem
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" encode_append.pl Dynamic.in par.exe Dynamic.pm
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" embed_files.pl -c 32768 par.exe "C:\STRAWB~1\perl\bin\perl524.dll" "C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll" "C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\libwinpthread-1.dll" "C:\Straw
berry\perl\bin\libstdc++-6.dll" > boot_embedded_files.c
# using "objdump" recusrively to find DLLs needed by par.exe
# embedding "par.exe" as "par.exe"
# embedding "C:/Strawberry/c/bin/libwinpthread-1.dll" as "libwinpthread-1.dll"
# embedding "C:/Strawberry/c/bin/libstdc++-6.dll" as "libstdc++-6.dll"
# embedding "C:/Strawberry/perl/bin/perl524.dll" as "perl524.dll"
# embedding "C:/Strawberry/c/bin/libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll" as "libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll"
gcc -c -s -O2 -DWIN32  -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields  -I"C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE"  -DPARL_EXE=\"parl.exe\" -DPAR_PAC
KER_VERSION=\"1.035\" -s -O2 boot.c
In file included from mktmpdir.h:85:0,
                 from mktmpdir.c:1,
                 from boot.c:10:
sha1.c: In function 'sha_transform':
sha1.c:146:2: warning: right shift count >= width of type
  T >>= 32;
  ^
g++ boot.o  -static-libgcc -s   -s -L"C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE" -L"C:\STRAWB~1\c\lib"  "C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\libperl524.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libmoldname.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-
w64-mingw32\lib\libkernel32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libuser32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libgdi32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libwinspool.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w
64-mingw32\lib\libcomdlg32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libadvapi32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libshell32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libole32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w
64-mingw32\lib\liboleaut32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libnetapi32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libuuid.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libws2_32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64
-mingw32\lib\libmpr.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libwinmm.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libversion.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libodbc32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw3
2\lib\libodbccp32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libcomctl32.a"  ppresource.coff -o boot.exe
rem
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" encode_append.pl Static.in boot.exe Static.pm
cp Static.pm ..\blib\lib\PAR\StrippedPARL\Static.pm
cp Dynamic.pm ..\blib\lib\PAR\StrippedPARL\Dynamic.pm
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -Mblib=.. run_with_inc.pl boot.exe -q -B -Oparl.exe
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command -e cp -- parl.exe ..\blib\script\parl.exe
rem ..\blib\script\parl.exe
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -Mblib=.. run_with_inc.pl par.exe -q -B -Oparldyn.exe
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command -e cp -- parldyn.exe ..\blib\script\parldyn.exe
rem ..\blib\script\parldyn.exe
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-Iinc" -MExtUtils::Command -e cp -- script/par.pl blib\script\par.pl
pl2bat.bat blib\script\par.pl
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-Iinc" -MExtUtils::Command -e cp -- script/pp blib\script\pp
pl2bat.bat blib\script\pp
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-Iinc" -MExtUtils::Command -e cp -- script/tkpp blib\script\tkpp
pl2bat.bat blib\script\tkpp
  RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.035.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe -- OK
Running make test
'No tests defined for myldr extension.'
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'inc', 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/00-pod.t t/10-parl-generation.t t
/20-pp.t t/30-current_exec.t t/40-packer_cd_option.t t/80-doublecolon.t t/90-rt101800.t t/90-rt103861.t t/90-rt104560.t t/90-rt104635.t t/90-rt59710.t
t/00-pod.t ............... skipped: Set environment variable PERL_TEST_POD=1 to test POD
t/10-parl-generation.t ... ok
t/20-pp.t ................ Can't locate loadable object for module IO in @INC (@INC contains: CODE(0x1e59984) .) at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 269.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 269.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 269.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Seekable.pm line 101.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Seekable.pm line 101.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/File.pm line 133.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/File.pm line 133.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/PAR/Heavy.pm line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/PAR/Heavy.pm line 19.
Compilation failed in require at -e line 158.
Can't locate File/Temp.pm in @INC (you may need to install the File::Temp module) (@INC contains: .) at -e line 6.
END failed--call queue aborted.

t/20-pp.t ................ 1/34 #   Failed test 'pp_hello_1
# [430]
# Test 1_0 The command string " a.exe " in directory C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\PAR-Packer-1.035-cDPIgz\contrib\automated_pp_test\pp_switch_tests\temp1,did not produce :: "hello" ::
# Instead, it produced :: 'a.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
# operable program or batch file. ::
# End of [430] results
#
# Did "c:\strawb~1\perl\bin\perl.exe" "C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\PAR-Packer-1.035-cDPIgz\blib\script\pp" "hello.pl"  produce a.exe?
# '
#   at automated_pp_test.pl line 6867.
Can't locate loadable object for module IO in @INC (@INC contains: CODE(0x1e498c4) .) at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 269.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 269.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 269.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Seekable.pm line 101.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Seekable.pm line 101.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/File.pm line 133.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/File.pm line 133.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/PAR/Heavy.pm line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/PAR/Heavy.pm line 19.
Compilation failed in require at -e line 158.
Can't locate File/Temp.pm in @INC (you may need to install the File::Temp module) (@INC contains: .) at -e line 6.
END failed--call queue aborted.
t/20-pp.t ................ 2/34 Can't locate loadable object for module IO in @INC (@INC contains: CODE(0x1e38cc4) .) at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 269.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 269.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 269.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Seekable.pm line 101.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Seekable.pm line 101.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/File.pm line 133.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/File.pm line 133.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/PAR/Heavy.pm line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/PAR/Heavy.pm line 19.
Compilation failed in require at -e line 158.
Can't locate File/Temp.pm in @INC (you may need to install the File::Temp module) (@INC contains: .) at -e line 6.
END failed--call queue aborted.

t/20-pp.t ................ 3/34 #   Failed test 'pp_minus_o_foo_foo_dot_pl_bar_dot_pl
# [430]
# Test 3_0 The command string " foo.exe " in directory C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\PAR-Packer-1.035-cDPIgz\contrib\automated_pp_test\pp_switch_tests\temp0,did not produce :: "hello foo" ::
# Instead, it produced :: 'foo.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
# operable program or batch file. ::
# End of [430] results
#
# Did "c:\strawb~1\perl\bin\perl.exe" "C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\PAR-Packer-1.035-cDPIgz\blib\script\pp" -o foo.exe "foo.pl" "bar.pl"  produce foo.exe?
# '
#   at automated_pp_test.pl line 6960.
t/20-pp.t ................ 5/34 Can't locate loadable object for module IO in @INC (@INC contains: CODE(0x1d696ac) .) at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 269.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 269.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 269.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Seekable.pm line 101.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Seekable.pm line 101.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/File.pm line 133.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/File.pm line 133.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/PAR/Heavy.pm line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/PAR/Heavy.pm line 19.
Compilation failed in require at -e line 158.
Can't locate File/Temp.pm in @INC (you may need to install the File::Temp module) (@INC contains: .) at -e line 6.
END failed--call queue aborted.
t/20-pp.t ................ 6/34 Can't locate loadable object for module IO in @INC (@INC contains: CODE(0x1ec9b34) .) at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 269.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 269.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 269.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Seekable.pm line 101.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Seekable.pm line 101.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/File.pm line 133.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/File.pm line 133.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/PAR/Heavy.pm line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/PAR/Heavy.pm line 19.
Compilation failed in require at -e line 158.
Can't locate File/Temp.pm in @INC (you may need to install the File::Temp module) (@INC contains: .) at -e line 6.
END failed--call queue aborted.
t/20-pp.t ................ 10/34 Can't locate loadable object for module IO in @INC (@INC contains: CODE(0x4c99f4) .) at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 269.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 269.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 269.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Seekable.pm line 101.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Seekable.pm line 101.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/File.pm line 133.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/File.pm line 133.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/PAR/Heavy.pm line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/PAR/Heavy.pm line 19.
Compilation failed in require at -e line 158.
Can't locate File/Temp.pm in @INC (you may need to install the File::Temp module) (@INC contains: .) at -e line 6.
END failed--call queue aborted.

t/20-pp.t ................ 11/34 #   Failed test 'pp_minus_e_print_hello
# [430]
# Test 11_0 The command string " a.exe " in directory C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\PAR-Packer-1.035-cDPIgz\contrib\automated_pp_test\pp_switch_tests\temp2,did not produce :: "hello" ::
# Instead, it produced :: 'a.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
# operable program or batch file. ::
# End of [430] results
#
# Did "c:\strawb~1\perl\bin\perl.exe" "C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\PAR-Packer-1.035-cDPIgz\blib\script\pp" -e "print qq[hello
# ];" produce a.exe?
# '
#   at automated_pp_test.pl line 7327.
t/20-pp.t ................ 13/34 C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\a4UGhRjY21 syntax OK
Can't locate loadable object for module IO in @INC (@INC contains: CODE(0x1e0b134) .) at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 269.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 269.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 269.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Seekable.pm line 101.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Seekable.pm line 101.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/File.pm line 133.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/File.pm line 133.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/PAR/Heavy.pm line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/PAR/Heavy.pm line 19.
Compilation failed in require at -e line 158.
Can't locate File/Temp.pm in @INC (you may need to install the File::Temp module) (@INC contains: .) at -e line 6.
END failed--call queue aborted.

t/20-pp.t ................ 14/34 #   Failed test 'pp_minus_c_hello
# [430]
# Test 14_0 The command string " a.exe " in directory C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\PAR-Packer-1.035-cDPIgz\contrib\automated_pp_test\pp_switch_tests\temp2,did not produce :: "hello" ::
# Instead, it produced :: 'a.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
# operable program or batch file. ::
# End of [430] results
#
# Did "c:\strawb~1\perl\bin\perl.exe" "C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\PAR-Packer-1.035-cDPIgz\blib\script\pp" -c "hello.pl"  produce a.exe?
# '
#   at automated_pp_test.pl line 7461.
Can't locate loadable object for module IO in @INC (@INC contains: CODE(0x4c9e74) .) at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 269.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 269.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 269.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Seekable.pm line 101.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/Seekable.pm line 101.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/File.pm line 133.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/lib/IO/File.pm line 133.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at c:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/PAR/Heavy.pm line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at c:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/PAR/Heavy.pm line 19.
Compilation failed in require at -e line 158.
Can't locate File/Temp.pm in @INC (you may need to install the File::Temp module) (@INC contains: .) at -e line 6.
END failed--call queue aborted.
```

Comment: "It would not install due to the error and I manually ran the makefile and forced installation." Forcing installation almost never works. (There's a reason the tests were failing!) You should [edit] your question to show the output from the build.

Comment: How are you installing PAR::Packer?  Using portable versions of Strawberry Perl 5.24.0.1 (32-bit & 64-bit), I used the command `cpan PAR::Packer` and was able to successfully install the module.  And I was able to successfully use the pp utility to create an executable from a Perl script.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, I understand that forcing it was unlikely to work.  I had tried to install PAR::Packer earlier and the installation seemed to work, however,it failed in the same way when I tried to run pp.  I uninstalled, and reinstalled perl, and when I tried to install `PAR::Packer` again it failed the unit tests.

Comment: Please show the output from the failing tests.

Comment: @dasgar, my initial attemps have been with the cpan command: `cpan PAR::Packer`.  When this didn't work, I ran the following as an attempt to force:
`cpan
look PAR::Packer
perl MakeFile.pl
dmake -f Makefile install`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, shall I post the entire thing?  The entire output is about 1000 lines.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Find the first failure in the log and post the output from there down. There's a test summary toward the end, but that doesn't have enough detail, so you'll need to go further back in the log. If that's not enough, you can always post the full output later.

Comment: I changed the question to reflect difficulty in installation rather than use, and ended up posting about a third of the output.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize the tests were showing the same error as you got when running pp. I see similar errors with Strawberry in one test [CPAN Testers](http://www.cpantesters.org/cpan/report/ca15d83f-6c19-1014-9833-216e2dace4d3), so it's not just you. How did you install Strawberry? Did you copy it or any modules from another machine?

Comment: Also, have you successfully installed any other modules with cpan?

Comment: No problem -- I was trying to show the minimal situation that caused the error, hence the forced installation.  I installed Strawberry from the msi directly from their site, completely clean installation.  Any modules not included in the distro were installed using the cpan command line.  I have been able to install others.  I just did Data::Dumper and Win32::GUI with no trouble.

Comment: In that case, it seems like a bug, not anything you did wrong. I would file a detailed [bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=PAR-Packer) for PAR::Packer.